Too many debug prints causes out of memory
For convenience, my program uses a lot of statements like
msg!("var: {:?}", var)

Eventually, this leads to
Program log: Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory


Is this because format! allocates memory to the heap and the heap is only 32K?
Is there a way to increase the heap's size, e.g. set it to 10MB? Something analogous to --compute-unit-limit of the solana-test-validator would be ideal.
The error message Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory doesn't appear anywhere in the codebase. What library is that from? Note that there is Error: Memory allocation failed (program-runtime/src/invoke_context.rs:115), but that's uppercase...
How would I compile a solana-test-validator variant with a bigger heap? I tried making these changes, but it wasn't enough

sdk/program/src/entrypoint.rs:37
pub const HEAP_LENGTH: usize = 1024 * 1024;

compute-budget/src/compute_budget_processor.rs:20
pub const MAX_HEAP_FRAME_BYTES: u32 = 1024 * 1024;


You're correct, the reason you're running out of space is because format! allocates heap memory (since it can't know the size of var in your example in advance) and the heap does not support free or realloc by default. Afaik, there's no way to specify a different heap size for local validators. That means you have two options:

Implement your own custom heap that better manages the memory that format! allocates so that it doesn't keep allocating more for each msg! call. An example for a custom heap in Rust by Solana can be found here.
Use less msg! calls / don't use the whole variable, but only the parts of it you care about in that context.


Thanks, I understand it better now! While investigating it, though, I stumbled on some other questions (see 3. and 4. in edit)
